# Is $\mathrm{d}x^2=\mathrm{d}(x^2)$ or $(\mathrm{d}x)^2$?

Tags: calculus

If we are given a metric, say $$\mathrm{d}s^2=\sum \mathrm{d}x_i^2$$ Does $\mathrm{d}x^2$ mean $\mathrm{d}(x^2)=(x+\mathrm{d}x)^2-x^2=2x\mathrm{d}x$ or $(\mathrm{d}x)^2=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: $(\Delta x)^2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)

Comment: @Math Attack. Thanks for pushing the inevitable daily question about $dx$, sorry $\mathbf{\color{red}{d}}x\,,$ to the active queue.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes sorry they already pointed it out to me, I didn't know they would rise to the top of the list (I was bored and wanted to try to get the "Archaeologist" badge and I had started modifying the differentials and the sizes of the brackets) anyway I won't do it again for a while and I will dilute them over time

Comment: @MathAttack when you put back on your mathematician's hat you may want to make a comment about how little interesting such d$x$ questions are. Of course only if you agree on that. In that case you could do that to zillions of same questions and I would not mind :) That one here is not even that bad. The typical example is far worse. "Is $dy/dx$ a fraction or not?". Yawn !

Comment: @KurtG. Ahahaha yes but I thought it would be a quick badge to get that wouldn't bother anyone (unfortunately I was wrong but the fact is that most of the old questions don't need major corrections because they have already been modified many times). If you have advice on what to edit that would be useful in the future, maybe I'll do that. I was thinking to modify for example the R,N,Z,C with $\mathbb{R,N,Z,C}$ but I didn't find many who wrote it wrong

Comment: @MathAttack Imho old questions should be left unless there is a serious mathematical error, or, as I said it is the question if $dy/dx$ is a fraction (don't forget to downvote it as well). Nonetheless: if you want to be an Archaeologist you have to look for low hanging fruits. Have fun.

Comment: @KurtG. but in fact I don't quite understand one thing (I discovered this site a few months ago so I don't know if things were different before) how is it possible that old trivial and poorly posed questions used to get very high scores and now new serious questions receive less ? Has there been a decrease in user participation or something similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149771/discussion-between-math-attack-and-kurt-g).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The later. 
Your statement $ds^2 = \sum dx_i^2$ is in essence just the Pythagorean theorem in the dimension of the metric space.